# how to add Strike through on original price and show cart rule discounted price

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, knockoutjs, shipping-address

[image]

add strike through on the price and show the discounted price after strick through price on the checkout shipping step summary section

Answer (score 0):

To add a strikethrough on the original price and display the discounted price after the strikethrough price in the checkout shipping step summary section in Magento 2, you'll need to make customizations to your theme's checkout templates. Specifically, you'll be working with the `shipping.html` template to achieve this effect. Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. **Create or Override the Shipping Template:**

   If you don't already have a custom theme, you might need to create one. If you have a custom theme or a child theme, navigate to your theme's directory. The `shipping.html` file is typically located at:

   ```
   app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
   ```

   If the `shipping.html` file doesn't exist, you'll need to create it in the above path.
2. **Edit the `shipping.html` Template:**

   Open the `shipping.html` template file in a code editor and locate the section where the price is displayed. You'll typically find something like this:

   ```html
   <span class="price">
       <text args="$shippingMethod.amount" />
   </span>
   ```

   Modify this section to include the strikethrough and discounted price:

   ```html
   <span class="old-price">
       <s><text args="$shippingMethod.amount" /></s>
   </span>
   <span class="new-price">
       <text args="$shippingMethod.discountedAmount" />
   </span>
   ```

   In this example, we've added a class for the old price and a class for the new price. The `discountedAmount` is a variable you'll need to provide in your JavaScript code.
3. **Add JavaScript to Set the Discounted Amount:**

   In your theme's `requirejs-config.js` file (located in the same directory as your `shipping.html` template), add a configuration to include a JavaScript file. If the file doesn't exist, create it:

   ```javascript
   var config = {
       map: {
           '*': {
               'customShippingScript': 'Magento_Checkout/js/custom-shipping-script'
           }
       }
   };
   ```
4. **Create the JavaScript File:**

   Create a new JavaScript file named `custom-shipping-script.js` in your theme's `Magento_Checkout/js` directory:

   ```
   app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/js/custom-shipping-script.js
   ```

   In this file, define the discounted amount based on your logic:

   ```javascript
   define([
       'jquery',
       'ko',
       'uiComponent'
   ], function ($, ko, Component) {
       'use strict';

       return Component.extend({
           initialize: function () {
               this._super();
               // Replace this with your logic to calculate the discounted amount
               var discountedAmount = 10.00; // Example discounted amount
               this.discountedAmount = ko.observable(discountedAmount);
           }
       });
   });
   ```
5. **Apply Styles:**

   Add CSS to style the old price (strikethrough) and the new price (discounted amount):

   ```css
   .old-price s {
       text-decoration: line-through;
   }

   .new-price {
       font-weight: bold; /* To emphasize the discounted price */
   }
   ```
6. **Flush Cache:**

   After making these changes, flush your Magento cache to ensure that your modifications take effect.

Remember that these steps provide a basic outline for achieving the desired effect. The actual implementation might vary based on your theme's structure and any additional customizations you have in your Magento instance.